# How to delete Backbone model from localStorage collection

Tags: backbone.js

I have created some models all saved in local storage collection. My challenge is how to delete a model fom the collection in local storage using one of the model attributes value. Below is extract of my code:

```
var Food = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
    title: '',
    calories: 0,
    date: '',
    history: false
}
});

var Foods = Backbone.Collection.extend({  
    model: Food,
localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('Health-Tracker')
});  
my_foods = new Foods({});

var ls = new Backbone.LocalStorage('Health-Tracker');
var res = ls.findAll();
var n = res.length;
var i, id;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    food = res[i];
    id = food['id'];
    title = food['title'];
    calories = food['calories'];
    date = food['date'];        
    history = food['history'];      
    //I am stuck here
    if (history) {      
        ls.remove(food); // Not working
        // I have also tried this
        ls.remove(id); // not working
    }
}
```

Note that history is set to true successfully for some models in other section of the bigger codes. Above is only where I need to take action if history value is true. And it is bad code for now.
Any assistance is appreciated

Comment: What is `Backbone.LocalStorage`? Please provide a link/documentation

Comment: `Backbone.LocalStorage` is not part of official backbone. and most famous `Backbone.LocalStorage` plugin doesn't seem to use this syntax. It looks like some in-house code

Comment: Backbone,LocalStorage allows us to define a folder in the local storage for the collection. I got part of the solution from earlier question in stackoverflow, see http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/8pHNG/ The solution works fine in retrieving and displaying models saved in the localstrorage. But it did not go far to address, changing model attribute, destroying model.These are of concern to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this app does not use server to store/retrieve data. All models are stored in the local storage. It is a very long process to use findAll() and remove() as I used above to delete from the localstorage.  The following was added to delete models from the local storage:

```
my_foods.fetch();
    my_foods.models.forEach(function(food){
        day = food.get('day');
        new_day = get_new_day();// this function isn't included above
        if (new_day > day) {
            food.destroy();         
        }
});
```